# windows phone 8.1 resolution issues

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone 8.1 app which has a lot of textual data. But when i go to settings > ease of access and increase the text size, the text gets bloated on the screen including the controls. Is there a way to handle this in the app?

Comment: Do you want bigger text with controls remain the same size?

Comment: I want to prevent increasing the size of anything on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the [`IsTextScaleFactorEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.istextscalefactorenabled.aspx) property to `false` on your controls.

If you ever need to manually determine the text scale-factor, you can get it from [`UISettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.textscalefactor.aspx).